# Can I JUST copy an Angular 8 Feature Module from one Angular App/Workspace to another?

Tags: angular

I have an angular 8 app, call it **ang8app1** for which i have successfully developed an auth *Feature Module*. Here is the tree.

```bsh
ang8app1\src\app\auth> tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is F2FB-4810
G:.
│   auth.guard.spec.ts
│   auth.guard.ts
│   auth.module.ts
│   auth.service.spec.ts
│   auth.service.ts
│   token-interceptor.service.spec.ts
│   token-interceptor.service.ts
│
├───error-dialog
│       error-dialog.component.css
│       error-dialog.component.html
│       error-dialog.component.spec.ts
│       error-dialog.component.ts
│
├───login
│       login.component.css
│       login.component.html
│       login.component.spec.ts
│       login.component.ts
│
└───register
        register.component.css
        register.component.html
        register.component.spec.ts
        register.component.ts
```

Can I JUST **copy** the Angular 8 Feature Module (eg auth) from one Angular App/Workspace (eg ang8app1) into another (eg ang8app2) and expect it to work, if i hook it up to ang8app2's app.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of the modules dependencies are self contained, you should be fine.

Are you referencing any of these dependencies outside of the module?

- installed packages
- environment variables
- other non-Angular modules
- css (a soft dependency, I guess)

Comment: Thanks, Kurt. This worked pretty good. I had to hook up app.module & app-routing.module, etc.